# Reg Exp matching multiple instances

Tags: regex

I have to match multiple instances of either "int(" or "der("

So the expression must match these strings

```
VVEH + int(ACC_X) + der(FL_WSP)
VVEH + int(ACC_X) + int(FL_WSP)
VVEH + der(ACC_X) + der(FL_WSP)
```

and not these

```
VVEH + int(ACC_X) + log(FL_WSP)
VVEH + der(ACC_X) + log(FL_WSP)
```

Comment: It may help if you also mentioned what flavour of regex you are using. Is it perl? javascript? .Net? something else?

Comment: I'm using Qt libs in C++

Answer (score 1):

```
VVEH( \+ (int|der)\([^)]+\)){2,}


VVEH            #Initial string
(
    \+          #Escape the 'plus'
    (int|der)   #Either of your function names
    \(          #Escape the bracket
    [^)]+       #Match anything inside the brackets
    \)          #Escape the bracket
){2,}           #All of that stuff above at least twice
```

Comment: This seems correct but it doesn't work for me, it works only with {1,}. I think could be a limitation/bug of QRegExp engine. Anyway thank you for the clear explanation.